# Object not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, callable

```
I am currently working on this code for my homework assignment involving Matrix Implementation:

class MyMatrix(object):
    def __init__(self, n, m, t):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
        self.t = t

        self.data = []
        for i in range(0, self.n):
            row = []
            for i in range (0, self.m):
                row.append(self.t())
            self.data.append(row)

    def set(self, i, j, v):
        self.data[i][j] = v

    def get(self, i, j):
        self.data[i][j]

    def __str__(self):
        n = self.__class__.__name__ + "({})".format((self.n,self.m))
        for i in range(0, self.n):
            for j in range(0, self.m):
                s += str(self.get(i,j)) + " "
            s += "\n"
        return s

class MySparseMatrix(MyMatrix):


    def __init__(self, n, m, t):
        self.n = n
        self.m = m
        self.t = t
        self.data = {}

    def set(self, i, j, v):
        key = (i, j)
        self.data[key] = v

    def get(self, i,j):
        key = (i, j)
        return self.data.get(key, self.t())
```

I am trying to print:

```
tt = MySparseMatrix(int, 2, 2)
tt.set(0,0,11)
tt.set(0,1,5)
tt.set(1,0,2)
print(tt.get(0,1))
print("tt = ", tt)
```

But it gives me

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this error? I am very new to Python.

Comment: Rather than pad the question with nonsense, please include the full traceback, not just the error message.

Comment: When the question editor prompts you to add more detail to your question, please don't just post gibberish. A key piece of detail missing from your question is the full traceback. Add the  full traceback to your question, verbatim.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling `self.t()` which is an integer `tt = MySparseMatrix(int, 2, 2)`. You pass integer value 2 to instance variable `t`. Find a meaningful name for your variables may help you avoid this kind of mistakes.

example:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> a()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

The last return line `self.t()`has the problem remove the paranthas. 
t is an integer and you are trying to do a method call which is causing the error.